# Melhor forma de captar os dados de uma query

Tags: php, sql

Tenho apresentada numa tabela de um site informações de uma base de dados desta maneira:

```
<?
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, nome FROM pessoas");
    //---------------DADOS------------------------
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    echo "<TABLE>";
    echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TD>".$row['id']."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$row['nome']."</TD>";
    echo "<TD> 
              <i class='fa fa-eye'></i>
              <i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>
              <i class='fa fa-trash'></i>  ";
    echo "</TR>";
    echo "</TABLE>";
    }

        ?>
```

Queria saber de alguma forma para passar os dados quando se clica nos icons da tag `<i>` para fazer uma query. Por exemplo o terceiro `<i>` é para quando se clica lá, fazer `DELETE` a um registo mas penso que com a tag `<form>` não dá.

Comment: Leia isso, antes de querer saber qual é a melhor forma: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas é possível usar a tag form para isso sim. Você deve criar um form para cada opção que quiser, como exclusão ou edição. A diferença é que você precisar de um input tipo submit para isso, no lugar do texto em i.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
echo "<form method='post' action='deleta.php'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."'> ";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Deletar'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Repare que coloquei valor do ID como um campo input tipo oculto. Dessa maneira você poderá acessá-lo na página PHP para onde o form enviar. O trabalho extra estaria em estilizar o botão de input para a maneira que precisar.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe a melhor forma, o que existe é a maneira que mais atende ao seu propósito, no caso abaixo, é um exemplo simples, utilizando PDO:

```
class Database {

        private static $servidor = 'localhost'; // Servidor, no caso poderia ser também localhost
        private static $usuario = 'root'; // usuário do banco de dados
        private static $senha = 'senha'; // senha do banco de dados
        private static $banco = 'banco'; // nome do banco de dados
        private static $instance = null;

        public static function getConnection() {
            if (!self::$instance instanceof PDO) {
                try {
                    self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' .
                    self::$servidor . ';dbname=' . 
                    self::$banco, 
                    self::$usuario, 
                    self::$senha);
                } catch (PDOException $exc) {
                    echo "Erro ao conectar :: {$exc->getMessage()}";
                }
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function fetchAll($query) {
            $con = self::getConnection();

            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

            $this->execute($stmt);

            if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
                return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null) {
            try {
                if (isset($data)) {
                    $stmt->execute($data);
                } else {
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
            } catch (PDOException $exc) {
                echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
            }
        }

        public function action($sql, array $data) {
            $con = self::getConnection();
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $this->execute($stmt, $data);
            if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
}

$conexao = new Database();

//listando...
$collection = $conexao->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM tabela");

foreach ($collection as $data) {
      echo $data['campo'] . '<br>';
}

//deletando...
 $deletou = $conexao->action('DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id=:id',array('id' => (int) $id));
 if ($deletou) {
   echo "apagou!";
 }

//inserindo
$insert = $conexao->action("INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) values (:campo1,:campo2)",array('campo1'=>'valor1','campo2'=>'valor2'));
 if ($insert) {
   echo "gravou!";
 }
//atualizando
$update = $conexao->action("UPDATE tabela SET campo1=:campo1, campo2=:campo2 where id=:id",array('campo1'=>'valor1','campo2'=>'valor2','id' => (int) $id));
 if ($update) {
   echo "atualizou!";
 }
```